# Html.fromHtml,Jsoup,String,XMLreader как вырезать определенный тег

Tags: java, android, html, строки, jsoup

Как вырезать все теги  из String
 или просто игнорировать их при выводе, или просто их не получать jsoup, слышал про XMLreader там вроде можно настроить под себя. Но неизвестно, что в следующий раз зальют на сайт. Использую Html.fromHtml для вывода текста с разметкой , получаю его через jsoup. И какой способ является менее скажется на производительности.

Вот пример html

```
    <td style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; text-indent: 25px;" align="justify">
        <p style="text-align: justify;">текст1</p>
        <p style="text-align: justify;">текст2</p>
        <p style="text-align: justify;">
<img alt="" src="/images/IMG_1367.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></p>
     </td>
```

Нужно вырезать этот тег `<img alt="" src="/images/IMG_1367.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">` количество изображений разное, может быть в любом месте (между текстом к примеру)

Получаю разметку так `Elements elements = document.select("td[style]"); newsContent = elements.html();`

Вывожу `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(newsContent));`

Хмл ридер крайний способ, я думаю тут много способов и мне интересно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Elements imgs = document.select("img");
document.remove(imgs);
Elements elements = document.select("td[style]"); 
newsContent = elements.html();
```

Comment: мне при этом нужно еще и получить img

Comment: @Артем, ну так они ж в переменной `imgs`...

Comment: разве он не вырезает их при подключении? У меня ошибка в чем может быть дело? remove() in Node cannot be applied

Comment: А все понял, все вопросы отпадают, я думал document.remove на connect идет

Comment: А нет все равно нефига непонятно document должен быть выбран главный ?(типо еще один select?)

Comment: Удаляет он вот так  Elements img = document.select("img[alt]").remove(); , но похоже нужно делать 2ной запрос.

Comment: А нет спасибо все получилось